# How To Post Data To Some External Php Without Redirecting & How To Loop Or Execute Some Php For Several Times

Tags: php, curl, sms

I'm trying to create sms floader and i have created the two following php files but when ever the user entered his mobile number its redirecting to another external website and please help me on how to get input from user to loop the same code for several times. like if the user they enter his mobilenumber and loop value to 10 times it should send 10 sms to destination number

**sms.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TrickzTracking | SMS Floader</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Nandan T Rsn" />
    <meta name="keyword" content="sms bomber,sms bomber 2016,working sms bomber,trickztracking sms bomber,unlimited sms bomber,anonymous sms bomber" />
    <meta name="description" content="Free SMS Bomber | TrickzTracking" />
    <meta name="contact" content="TrickzTracking@Gmail.com" />
    <meta name="copyright" content="Copyright (c)2015-2016 
TrickzTracking. All Rights Reserved." />


    <style>

body {
  background: #3b5998;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #FDFCFB;
  text-align: center;
}
#id1{
color: #000000;
}
input{
    margin: 5px;
}
.input{
    margin: 5px;
}

form {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 17% auto;
  margin-top:90px;

}


.header {
  font-size: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}


.description {
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  margin: -2px 0 45px;
}




.button {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 44px;
  border: none;
}


#email,#number,#message,#times {
  width: 70%;
  background: #FDFCFB;
  font-family: inherit;
  color: #737373;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-indent: 5%;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}


#submit {
  width: 31%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 46px;
  background: #E86C8D;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: inherit;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}


#submit:hover {
  background: #d45d7d;
}


input:focus {
  outline: none;
  outline: 2px solid #E86C8D;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #E86C8D;
}


    </style>

    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
  <body>

<form action="sms_api.php" method="post" name="SMS Floader">

      <div class="header">
         <p>Bomb your friends</p>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <p>Now, you can bomb your Friends number by simply using their numbers in the below form </p>
      </div>
      <div class="input">
         <input type="text" class="button" id="number" name="num" placeholder="XXXXXXXXXX" maxlength="10" value="">

        <button type="submit" class="button" onclick="submit">Start</button>
      </div>
<div class="">
        <h4> Terms And Conditions : </h4>
      </div>
<div class="description">
        <p id="id1">1.   Don't Try To Fload On Unknow Person's. </p>
        <p id="id1">2.   Send Only Maximum Of 50 SMS On The Go.</p>
        <p id="id1">2.   Your IP Will Be Logged For Security Purpose.</p>
<p>Powered By: <a href="https://www.trickztracking.com.com/">www.TrickzTracking.com</a></p>
      </div>
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

**sms_api.php**

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">
function submit(myForm){
document.myForm.submit();
}
</script>

<body onLoad="javascript:submit(myForm)">

<form action="http://www.some-other-website.com/sms/api.php" method="post" name="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="message" value="102310">
    <input type="hidden" name="num" value="<?php echo $_POST['num'] ?>">
    <input name="hidden" type="submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Ps: when ever sms.php send post data to sms_api.php its redirecting it to http://www.some-other-website.com/sms/api.php instead i want that to redirect to sms.php after posting data to http://www.some-other-website.com/sms/api.php

I'm new to php please help me :D

Answer (score 0):

You are using a on load submit function, which will submit the form as soon as the 
sms_api is called. The coding format is wrong and so is the concept. You should try making a single form rather than trying to complex the code. Keep it simple.

Comment: I'm very poor in php will you help me in this case..?

Comment: In you sms_api.php add 
`<form action="http://www.some-other-website.com/sms/api.php" method="post" name="Form" id="subb">    
     <input type="hidden" id="num" name="num" value="<?php echo $num ?>">
     <input name="hidden" type="submit" id="btn">
 </form>
 <?php }?>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if( $("#num").val() > 0) {
      $("#btn").trigger("click");
    }
     if($("#btn").trigger("click")){
       alert("submitted");
       window.location.replace("http://localhost/test.php");
     }
  });
 </script>`

Comment: sorry i am new here and I cannot indent the code
My apologies

Comment: i removed this "<?php }?>" and now its showing submitted window but its not posting data to that external link :(

Comment: according to the code posted your form will submit to www.some-other-website.com/sms/api.php and then redirect to form again.
 I will show you the demo in code pen later